# Rails 4 scaffold generator Testing controller action update fails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller

I am using ruby "2.0.0" and 'rails', '~> 4.0.0' and 'rspec-rails', "2.14.2" ( quoted from the Gemfile. I have two entirely  different apps and I am getting the same error on both.

I used the scaffold generator for my controller. So it also generated my controller tests. In particular the update action broke right away. 
Test code

```
  describe "PUT update" do
describe "with valid params" do
  it "updates the requested product" do
    product = Product.create! valid_attributes
    # Assuming there are no other products in the database, this
    # specifies that the Product created on the previous line
    # receives the :update_attributes message with whatever params are
    # submitted in the request.
    expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:update).with({ "product_name" => "Product 1" })
    put :update, {:id => product.to_param, :product => { "product_name" => "Product 1" }}, valid_session
  end
```

Controller code:

```
 # PATCH/PUT /products/1
```

# PATCH/PUT /products/1.json

def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

So i run my test and:

```
  1) ProductsController PUT update with valid params updates the requested product
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
   Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: update
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-mocks-3.0.2/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance/recorder.rb:92:in `verify'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-mocks-3.0.2/lib/rspec/mocks/space.rb:69:in `block in verify_all'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-mocks-3.0.2/lib/rspec/mocks/space.rb:69:in `each_value'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-mocks-3.0.2/lib/rspec/mocks/space.rb:69:in `verify_all'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-mocks-3.0.2/lib/rspec/mocks.rb:45:in `verify'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/mocking_adapters/rspec.rb:21:in `verify_mocks_for_rspec'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:354:in `verify_mocks'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:345:in `run_after_example'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:163:in `block in run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `call'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Procsy>'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:174:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:430:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `call'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Procsy>'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:430:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `call'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Procsy>'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:432:in `run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:485:in `run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:303:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:145:in `run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:494:in `block in run_examples'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `map'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `run_examples'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:457:in `run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `block in run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `map'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `block in run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `map'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `map'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block in run_specs'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:54:in `report'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 # /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
 # 
 #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
 #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
 #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
```

Finished in 0.27911 seconds (files took 1.85 seconds to load)
16 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/products_controller_spec.rb:90 # ProductsController PUT update with valid params updates the requested product

I am posting the response after this, the problem is solved:

Comment: So a good friend took a glance at my code and he pointed out that: expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:update).with({ "product_name" => "Product 1" })
So the fix consists in adding :update_attributes to the tests in order to make the call to the model, instead as a controller action as it was doing before. So:  expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:update_attributes).with({ "product_name" => "Product 1" })
And now the test pass. I hope this helps. I am fairly new to Rails, so please bear with any accuracies or errors. Feel free to report typos or corrections. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a good friend took a glance at my code and he pointed out that:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:update).with({ "product_name" => "Product 1" })
```

Is trying to receive an update from the model. There is no update method on the model:

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :normalize_name, on: :create
  validates :product_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :product_cost, presence: true, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1 }

  protected
    def normalize_name
      self.product_name = self.product_name.downcase.titleize
    end
end
```

So the fix consists in adding :update_attributes to the tests in order to make the call to the model, instead as a controller action as it was doing before.

```
        expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:update_attributes).with({ "product_name" => "Product 1" })
```

And now the test pass.

I hope this helps. I am fairly new to Rails, so please bear with any inaccuracies or errors. Feel free to report typos or corrections, they are always welcome.